# How to handle local requests to Doorkeeper using React.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5, doorkeeper

I have a Rails app that has an API witch handles requests from various sources such as iOS apps and Android, they work fine, I store the user and password on the App and handle the tokens accordingly.

The problem is I have decided to add React.js on the App since Rails5 has started supporting webpack, and it needs to get information from the backend, I naturally chose to use the existing API infrastructure for the task, however since react.js is nothing more than js, I do not wish to save tokens or password info, I currently have circumvented the problem by just passing the token through to by data attributes in the DOM,

```
Doorkeeper::AccessToken.find_or_create_for(Doorkeeper::Application.first, @current_user.id, nil, 10.days, true)
```

It does the trick by for obvious security reasons I do not like the current method, any suggestion on how to do it? should I create another scheme to get information?